# javascript:if statement

Tags: javascript

How to execute the if statement only when both the inputs are different not when both inputs are same.
suppose:

```
var a=prompt("have Input","");
var b=prompt("have Input","");
if(a && !b){alert("ok")}
else{"wrong"}
```

the above condition works when both the inputs are true ,when both the inputs are false and when **a** is true and **b** is false but if **a** is false and **b** is true the if statement dont get executed .How to solve this issue through if statement.What is the way to get my problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a logical exclusive-or (XOR) operation. There are some Javascript examples [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/xor.html). My favorite (for being unexpected and simple) is:

```
if (foo ? !bar : bar) {
    ...
}
```

Admittedly, this is a little unusual coding, and verges on being "too clever". Sometimes if a language does not have direct syntax for an operation the code just has to be verbose, like getting the quotient and remainder from a division operation.

Comment: I've never seen `if (foo ? !bar : bar)` in code, and if I did, I'm sure as hell I would have a talk with you my fellow developer.

Comment: @JanDvorak, please wait a few minutes before downvoting to see if the answer gets expanded. SO moves so quickly one often needs to answer very quickly and then revise.

Comment: I disagree. I always rate answers, not their potential. If an answer improves, so does my vote. If the answer is so short it's useless, so be it.

Answer (score 7):

if you need that a and b would be different isn't `if (a != b)` enough?

Comment: Depending on the case it's better to do `!a != !b` to always deal with booleans.

Comment: @elclanrs I believe the inputs should be treated as strings.

Comment: Does this work when a and b are not identical but both "falsy" (or is it "falsish")? I forget how Crockford puts it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( a===b)
{
     "Wrong"
}
else
{
     alert("Ok");
}
```